# No source attached for android third party library

Tags: android, eclipse-plugin, adt

Today in my android project I have add an external android library (I have build this project with is Library android property checked), and when I'm debugging my library code the eclipse doesn't attach the source code, making it almost impossible to do an effective debug.

Does anyone have this problem too? I'm using Eclipse Indigo on Mac OSX 10.7 with Android Plugin version 18.0.0

Answer (score 0):

Right click on you project -> build path -> configure built path -> libraries -> choose the library you want to attach source -> expand -> select source attachment -> edit -> enter the path to the source folder